# Debug Azure Function (Python) in VSCode and RuntimeError: Can't listen for client connections: [WinError 10048]

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

trying as usual debug locally Azure Function (Python) in VSCode and getting error

py process with Id=10296 started
[23/07/2020 21:31:41] Traceback (most recent call last):
RuntimeError: Can't listen for client connections: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Day before everything worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

found, I have added
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT =10 to local settings. And it tries start python worker again and again with the same port 10 times.